# Bash JQ filter code not run properly between DO -> DONE (WINDOWS + GITBASH)

Tags: json, bash, jq, mingw-w64, for-in-loop

I am running a piece of JQ filter code. This is been run on a Windows Server 2016 with GIT BASH.

the code looks like the following:
(don't mind the echo's and echo $i, this is for verbose reasons)

```
FILENAME="c:\Test\output4p.json"
for i in $(cat "$FILENAME" | jq -r .[].personnelNumber); do 
  echo $i
  echo
  jq '.[] | select(.personnelNumber=="'$i'")' "$FILENAME"
  echo
   done
```

it partly seems to run fine but sadly the output is.
[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNK7Z.png)

so I on purpose remove the -r in the top JQ code to have a look what is actually going wrong.

```
$ "C:\TEST\echo.sh"
"3633014"

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting ';' or ')' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
")                                 33014"
jq: 1 compile error



"3634594"

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting ';' or ')' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
")                                 34594"
jq: 1 compile error



"3634708"

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting ';' or ')' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
")                                 34708"
jq: 1 compile error



"3634847"

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting ';' or ')' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select(.personnelNumber==""3634847"")
jq: 1 compile error
```

if there is only 1 person in the json everything works as expected.
but when there are more, the code only runs properly on the last person in the "For i in $cat" list.

someone else encounter something like this before?

thank you guys in advance

I am first making making a loop based upon the personnelNumber.
Than for each personnelNumber I want to print the full array (which doesn't have an array ID)
When this is working fine I'm going to take this code further into a curl command.

Comment: If the only purpose of those exported numbers is to re-import them again for querying the same source, you should consider not leaving jq, and perform iteration and query in one go.

Comment: Thank you for you input, but the purpouse of this is that in between for eacht number a curl command with a specific API URL (inc. $i) is run.
and in the JQ code im working on now should be used to fill the data section of that curl command with JSON information.

Comment: Then try out the command-line options `--arg` and `--argjson` (depending on your field's datatype), e.g. `jq --argjson i "$i" '.[] | select(.personnelNumber == $i)' "$FILENAME"`

Comment: that doesnt make a difference, the problem is that it seems to run incomplete code for the everybody except the last person.
if i do a test with a curl request command for example, the first 3 lines are missing like 90 caracter positions (i check this by putting echo in front.)

Comment: That weirdly-formatted error message makes me suspect you've got DOS/Windows line endings somewhere, and are getting a (mostly-invisible) carriage return character in `$i`. This can cause [all sorts of weird problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571). Replace `echo $i` with `echo "'$i'" | LC_ALL=C cat -vt`. If `$i` just has the number, that should print `'33014'`; if it has a carriage return, you'll get something like `'33014^M'`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson your the man! exacly what was going on!
i echoed the `echo "'$i'"  | LC_ALL=C cat -vt` and ik got an output as `'3634594^M'`
i starded to read you link and went to the Cygwin Section, added this line of code in the top of my code `set -o igncr` , now it runs as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Comment of Gordon Davisson was exacly what was going on.

> That weirdly-formatted error message makes me suspect you've got DOS/Windows line endings somewhere

Gordon passed me over a link to a earlyer post of something quite similar.

[Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

I added the this piece of code to the top and i got all the correct outcommes.

```
set -o igncr
```

So conclusion, if you are running GITBASH or any Cygwin BASH make sure the Carriage Return in line endings are correct.